# Fill panel with rectangles

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I want to fill a panel with rectangles, and when the panel is resized, the rectangles should resize as well.

Why doesn't the following work?

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I would prefer not to use a `Grid` because of the pain of adding/removing columns and rearranging the children.  (I was looking forward to `StackPanel` because if I wanted to add a yellow `Rectangle` at the beginning, I just declare it.  I don't have to re-order the others by hand.)

Comment: Note that the reason StackPanel doesn't work is that StackPanel never gives its children more than their DesiredSize in the stacking direction.  Since a Rectangle's DesiredSize is zero all three rectangles are collapsed to nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or a UniformGrid:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Aha! I had forgotten all about UniformGrid.  That fits perfectly with what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `StackPanel` whose behavior is to take the size of its children. Use a `Grid` which takes the whole available size:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" />
  <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="1" />
  <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Bleh.  Have any solution that doesn't require the use of a Grid?  I don't want to have to add a new RowDefinition every time I decide to increase the number of Rectangles.